# Extra characters in XTerm printerCommand output

Tags: xterm

I've set up [`.Xresources`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/80c92286d6c637c848dbac73c531a0745e9ba8be/.Xresources) to be able to print the terminal contents to a file when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>:

```
XTerm*printAttributes: 2
XTerm*printerCommand: cat - > "`mktemp --tmpdir xterm-screenshot.bin.XXXXXXXXXX`"
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override Meta <KeyPress> P: print() \n
```

This seems to work fine, except that each line in the output is prefixed by some escape characters and the literal `#5`. Compare the output at the start of the `xterm` session:

```
user^2@host:~
$
```

Is that `ESC#5ESC[0m` bit at the start normal?

`less /tmp/xterm-screenshot.bin.*`:

```
ESC#5ESC[0muserESC[0;1;33m^2ESC[0m@host:ESC[0;1;34m~ESC[0m
ESC#5ESC[0m$ ESC[0m
```

`less -R /tmp/xterm-screenshot.bin.*`:

```
[0muser^2@host:~
[0m$
```

Additional info:

```
$ xterm -version
XTerm(271)
$ uname -a
Linux user 3.2.0-27-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 14:46:35 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since you specifically requested xTerm to `print()` with all the attributes:

```
XTerm*printAttributes: 2
```

i.e. the output file contains the whole sequence of bytes sent to xTerm and then you are using `less` (plain, with no switch) to *read* the file so you get the text version of what appeared on the terminal (stuff with all kind of attributes). The file in question is:

```
[me ~]$ file -b /tmp/xterm-screenshot.bin.HBsmSPRrFx
ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators, with escape sequences
```

You'll have to use `-r` (`--raw-control-chars`) with `less` in order to *view* the file content the same way it appeared on terminal:

```
less -r /tmp/xterm-screenshot.bin.HBsmSPRrFx
```

If you don't want the escape sequences in your output file (that is, you want a plain text file with no graphical attributes) you have to use:

```
XTerm*printAttributes: 0
```

in your `~/.Xresources`.
From [xTerm manual](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xterm.1.html):

```
printAttributes (class PrintAttributes)
    Specifies whether to print graphic attributes along with the text. A real DEC VTxxx terminal
    will print the underline, highlighting codes but your printer may not handle these. A "0"
    disables the attributes. A "1" prints the normal set of attributes (bold, underline, inverse
    and blink) as VT100-style control sequences. A "2" prints ANSI color attributes as well.
```

Comment: Ah, I get it - I was using `less -R` rather than `less -r`.